# multiple runs of a program, but different output

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an ActionBlock(TPL Dataflow) with the following sintax:

```
public ActionBlock(Func<TInput, Task> action, ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions);
```

and inside I define a Func and a Max degree of parallelism(which is greater than 1). My question is: how can I find out when the first thread has ended its execution(using a 'int contor' for example, for contoring every thread end)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `ActionBlock`? Is this part of TPL Dataflow?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it is

Comment: The reason you use something like an `ActionBlock` is to not be concerned with the implementation details of how the work is scheduled, merely what work needs to be done.  If you need to know specific details of how it's doing the work, odds are you shouldn't be using it (or you shouldn't need to know those implementation details, one of the two).

Comment: @Servy I need to know when the first task is done. Do you have a recommendation what to use instead of actionBlock ?

Comment: @Nica `await` it.